# Getting the path with a function key

Tags: key-bindings, path

I need to get the path and file name out of the open file.  Wrinkle .. The file is FTP'd to my Desktop and I need the Linux path.

I found this on the web that prints the path file name

```
noremap <silent> <F4> :let @+=expand("%:p")<CR>
```

I get this
 `C:\Users\rr243319\AppData\Local\Temp\scp30622\bcs\lgnt\clientapp\etscmbn\scripts\combine-ctc.pl`

I need

`C:/Users/rr243319/AppData/Local/Temp/scp30622/bcs/lgnt/clientapp/etscmbn/scripts/combine-ctc.pl`

Question : How do I convert the path to a linux like path?

Comment: Try `set shellslash` before doing the expand.

Comment: [shellslash option help](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'shellslash')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stores the current filename in the system clipboard with backslashes replaced with forward slashes:

```
noremap <silent> <F5> :let @+ = substitute(expand("%:p"), '\', '/', 'g')<cr>
```